# Can an American citizen schooling abroad join the airforce?

Tags: military, usa

I am a citizen of the U.S who is studying abroad from the age of 9.

If I am to Apply to become a test pilot will there be any impediments?

Due to security issues as it deals with classified aircrafts.

Aviation is something I really want to get into and I plan on taking aerospace for my college course, becoming a test pilot is an overlap of both worlds and is something I always wanted to be. I feel such reasons could be a hindrance.

Any links and answers will be much appreciated and If this question is not within guidelines a point in the right direction would awesome.

Comment: In which countries have you been studying? It probably won’t make any difference. Also, you do realize that there is no way to apply to be a test pilot ar entry into the military. You would have to serve as a pilot first before getting the opportunity to be a test pilot.

Comment: Why do you think a US citizen wouldn’t be allowed to join the US Air Force? Whether you have a shot at becoming a pilot (much less a test pilot) is a separate matter.

Comment: It is very **possible** for you to become a military test pilot. Follow these steps. Move back to the US. Get into a university. Join AFROTC. Graduate from both. Pass the FBI background check. Join the military. Become an officer or warrant officer (for helicopters). Become a military pilot. Serve and gain experience as a military pilot. Apply for test pilot school. By the time you apply to test pilot school, it won’t make any difference that you spent 10 years living abroad.

Comment: You may still be able to become a military test pilot without moving back to the states or graduating ROTC before your background check. It just makes the process more difficult. Unless, of course, you were overseas because your parents were serving a diplomatic or military mission. Living in an allied country or a community of American expats would help the process of the FBI background check as well. Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Thomas

Comment: @Dean, indeed, that's a valid answer, you should have posted it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which countries have you been studying? It probably won’t make any difference. Also, you do realize that there is no way to apply to be a test pilot ar entry into the military. You would have to serve as a pilot first before getting the opportunity to be a test pilot.

It is very **possible** for you to become a military test pilot. Follow these steps. Move back to the US. Get into a university. Join AFROTC. Graduate from both. Pass the FBI background check. Join the military. Become an officer or warrant officer (for helicopters). Become a military pilot. Serve and gain experience as a military pilot. Apply for test pilot school. By the time you apply to test pilot school, it won’t make any difference that you spent 10 years living abroad.

You may still be able to become a military test pilot without moving back to the states or graduating ROTC before your background check. It just makes the process more difficult. Unless, of course, you were overseas because your parents were serving a diplomatic or military mission. Living in an allied country or a community of American expats would help the process of the FBI background check as well. Read about [Andy Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Thomas), an astronaut from Australia that did not even become a US citizen until he was 30.

Comment: Some clarifications:  USAF doesn't have warrant officers (Army does). USAF helo pilots are commissioned officers. Study for BS in engineering or math. In AFROTC, apply for pilot school. Selection is before you graduate, but you can keep applying after graduation if you don't make it while in ROTC. Background check is done before graduation. When you graduate, you get commissioned the same day. At that point, you're in the military. He can also apply to the AF Academy, but getting a nomination while living overseas is a challenge. I suggest contacting an academy admissions counselor.